# Primefaces dataTable is duplicated on page

Tags: datatable, jsf-2, primefaces, duplication

Have review(for adding review or comments) component in my application.
When add review, that `p:dataTable` is updated with ajax.

***before adding review:***
[image]
***after adding first review***
[image]
***refresh page(F5):***
[image]
***after adding second review:***
[image]

jsf:

```
<h:form onsubmit="return commValidator();">
 <h:inputText value="#{comment.commentator}"/>
 <h:inputTextarea value="#{comment.body}";"/>
 <p:commandButton  value="send" action="#{showProducts.addComment}" update="comms"/>
 <p:dataTable id="comms" value="#{showProducts.comments}" var="com">   
  <p:column>#{com.commentator}(
   <h:outputText value="#{com.postDate}">
   </h:outputText>):
  </p:column>
  <p:column>#{com.body}</p:column>
 </p:dataTable> 
</h:form>
```

The problem is `p:dataTable` component is displayed twice on page.
After new review been added, that newly created `p:dataTable` displayed.
How to make `p:dataTable` displayed already after go to page and once time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p:dataList` component resolves this problem

It displays ones and new elem. is added to already existing list instead of creating new one list as with `p:dataTable`!

[forum](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=630)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem: p:dataTable inside form is duplicated, each time an update(:form) is made.

One possibility to solve the problem is to put a p:outputPanel as major element inside the form which contains all other elements. 
When simply doing an update(:form:outputpanel) the table is update BUT not duplicated anymore.